# SWRevealViewController Build Error

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AppDelegate", referenced from: objc-class-ref in main.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am trying to use `SWRevealViewController` in my project, it gives above error.
I dragged and dropped both files i.e. `SWRevealViewController.h` and `SWRevealViewController.m` in my project.

Comment: did you add bridging header when it asked?

Comment: Yes, already I added in my project...!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using these files in swift project then please make sure **#import "SWRevealViewController.h"** in your Bridging Header file.

Comment: yeah the file was missing in compile resource thats the reason. Good Job

Answer (score 1):

> Updated:

Please follows the below steps;

**click on the your project name  -> Click on Build Phases tab -> Compile Sources and then check to see whether SWRevealViewController.m is actually added to the list. If not, click + button -> Type SWRevealViewController.m -> Select and then Add it.
After that clean the project then again build and run.**

[image]

Enjoy..!